# WCF DataServiceQuery for derived type

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a base entity, and a derived entity, with an extra boolean property. My WCF Data Service exposes an EntitySet of the base entity. I can query it in a browser:

```
http://myserver/myservice/BaseSet/Namespace.Derived()?$filter=(BoolProp eq false)
```

And I get a collection of objects of my Derived type. All good.

In my client I have a grid which takes a DataServiceQuery. So I constructed my query:

```
var query = context.CreateQuery<Proxy.Derived>("BaseSet");
```

But when I try to filter on derived properties it returns an error. And when I examined the URL it used in its request it's missing the chunk for my derived type, i.e. it looked like:

```
http://myserver/myservice/BaseSet()?filter=(BoolProp eq false)
```

What's the proper way to construct a DataServiceQuery that I can use to query using properties on my derived type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was to extend the entitySetName argument to include my derived type:

```
var query = context.CreateQuery<Proxy.Derived>("BaseSet/Namespace.Derived")();
```

The name of the argument isn't great. Now I actually bother to read the documentation it *does* tell me that the entitySetName should be "A string that resolves to a URI." Not sure that helps most people but I should have checked it sooner.